# Formatting date sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to format existing dates in a column called `mydate` in a table called `empl`. However, I am going no where with this. I have tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mydate,103) from empl
```

but  get a `missing expression error`.

I want to change the current format in the column which is in the format

`dd-mm-yy` to `mm/dd/yy`

EDIT: im using oracle

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shall we guess that you are using SQL-Server (because of the `CONVERT()` or Oracle (because of the error)?

Comment: Date columns do not have a format. What is the datatype of the column `mydate`?

Comment: its the name of the column

Comment: What is the datatype? `DATE`, `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, `NUMBER`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datatype of the column is `DATE`, you can use the **[`TO_CHAR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)** function:

```
SELECT to_char(mydate, 'mm/dd/yy')
FROM empl ;
```

Comment: Thanks, there were no decent tutorials for this online!

Comment: @user1992697: it's all in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#i88891

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change the column type to date?  Then you could use date_format

Comment: Sorry - I was answering as if you had mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The Convert statement you show is for MS-SQL, and you would want code 3 not 103, the 100 series give 4 digit years.
Try:
`select to_char(mydate,'MM/DD/YY') from empl`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mydate is stored in date datatype, and using oracle, easy way to do that is:
select to_char(mydate, 'dd/mm/yy') from empl

In Oracle, convert is used to change character set with parameters
(char, destination_char_set, source_char_set)

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') CHRDATE from dual;
```